# cakephp auth component for editing info

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to make a link to edit a user's info. The url for a person with id 1 would be users/edit/1

```
echo $this->Html->link('Edit Info', array( 
   'controller' => 'users',  
   'action' => 'edit',
    AuthComponent::user('id')
));
```

The URL shows up correctly. However, I'm trying to restrict it so only the user with that id can edit their page. So, say user 4 tries to edit user 1's info, it will redirect.

This is part of the action for edit in UsersController that should redirect.

```
if($id !== AuthComponent::user('id')){
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=> 'index'));
    }
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cake/app/Controller/UsersController.php on line 42
```

**edit - got it to work, thanks for the help**

Answer (score 1):

You probably dont want to do it the way you are describing. If i were you i would make a separate route to something like `/profile/edit` And then have that go to a specific action in the `user` controller. In that action you would get the logged in users userid from the session, look up the user and then show them the edit view for their information.

This would leave you with link generation looking like:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Edit Info', array( 
   'controller' => 'users',  
   'action' => 'edit_profile'
));
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do it with routings but I got it to work using the method above.